# Is there a way to send a discord.js message into a specfic channel?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I found this, but it does not work and says send is undefined. Anyone know why?

```
client.channels.cache.get("channelidwashere").send(sellembed1)
```

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken the way you're trying to send a message is outdated

Try this:

```
const channel = await client.channels.fetch('youridhere');
await channel.send(embed1);
```

Edit: I got it from the docs right here: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ChannelManager
client.channels returns a ChannelManager, so you should be able to call the methods you find on this page.

Comment: The user's method is not exactly outdated, rather the channel was most likely uncached. Your answer would solve the problem though.